# Trying to contact a user for permission to print an answer in a book

Tags: support, copyright

I apologize in advance for breaking protocol. I'm just looking to get an official okay on rewriting and publishing Red Orca's answer in this [thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139831/is-there-a-proper-way-to-categorize-magic-items-as-minor-or-major-magic-items?answertab=oldest#tab-top) in an upcoming book about Magic Items. I looked for alternative ways to contact them but fell short. It's an incredible answer and I'd love to make it more widely known to people out there looking to categorize their own items.

They can reach out over reddit to u/griff-mac or Discord to griffmac#9421, if that's more appropriate. Thanks in advance, and again, I hope I'm not breaking rules too egregiously.

Cheers!

Comment: I have been summoned! I'm glad you found my answer useful. Could you provide some more detail about the book? How will my answer be used in it? How will you sell/distribute the book?

Comment: @RedOrca, I make magic items for a living. It's a strange life/world to be in. I'm publishing a hardcover book like the core materials that include 365 new magic items, illustrated and balanced between me and the community. I'd like to be able to clarify the differences between major and minor rarities, and your answer in that thread has always been enlightening. 

However, based on what's in the SRD, I'm not actually sure if I can legally include that rarity information in an official publication. At this point, I may just include a link to your comment for my followers to refer to.

Comment: @RedOrca Thanks for answering the call. :-)

Comment: @GriffinMacaulay FYI, any post has a "share" link in its lower left which will give you a short URL linking to the post. For answers, it will come in the form `https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/(numbers)/(more numbers)`. The first set of numbers is a reference to the post ID. The second set of numbers is your user ID and is used for tracking referrals for some badges. People will be able to take that ID to look up your profile. I tell you this because you can delete the user ID portion; some prefer to do this so that others cannot also look up their profile, but this is up to you.

Comment: @GriffinMacaulay That's an interesting point about rarity information. A link to my answer sounds like the best solution (and works within the existing license). Let me know if that isn't enough for your purposes. The best way to contact me in the future is to leave a comment on one of my answers/questions. That way, I get an inbox ping.

Comment: @RedOrca will do! Thank you for the clarity. I'll just make a link to it for my supporters and followers to reference. It really is the best answer online for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The fast way

[Content on RPG.se is already licensed for reuse.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) You can immediately reuse anything on RPG.se so long as you follow [the license conditions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).

If after reading that you’re not sure how to integrate a piece of Creative Commons content into a larger work, consult [CreativeCommons.org](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) and, if necessary (read: is recommended), your lawyer or your publisher’s lawyer.

### The direct way

The license here doesn’t eliminate the author’s original copyright, of course. Getting a license directly from the author is possible and then it has nothing to do with the CC license that content here is published under.

We don’t have a messaging system though, so there’s no on-site way to contact someone. [Red Orca](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/47185/red-orca) doesn’t have any contact info on their user profile, but they were last active within the last day, so if they see this, they might reach out here.

Comment: Theres no direct messaging system, but isn’t it possible to create a chat room and invite a specific user to said room? That essentially would serve the same function (though it isn’t a private conversation and, unless its a gallery chat room, anyone who comes across it can comment in it)

Comment: @Liam Hm, maybe. Asking someone in chat how that works might help; I’m not super familiar with the ins and outs of chat anymore. (Last I knew, they had to already be active in chat, and only mods could super-message anyone.)

Comment: Im just going off of what it says in the privileges under chat. Its worth noting that a user needs 100 rep to open a chat room, which the OP currently doesnt have. An amusing thought i just had, the main Chat goes off your combined network score. Theoretically, a user could join up with 100 different SE sites (theres at least 120 by my count, but i stopped counting sometime around M) and gain enough rep to make a chat room.

Comment: @LiamMorris (Un)fortunatly, the combined network score doesn't work that way. The baseline 1 rep and 100 rep association bonus is shared among the stacks and doesn't stack with itself.

Comment: Note that licensing for this site's content is currently boondoggled for anything older than [September  5th of this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0/333094#333094).  This means the link in the link in this answer is wrong; it should redirect [here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) instead of [here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode)

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Me advising someone to disregard the license under which SE offers content and instead use it under a different license would be me giving legal advice as if I’m a lawyer, which I will not do. I will also not mislead someone as to which license content is in fact being offered under by SE, regardless of any possible error in SE’s offer, since that would be legally irresponsible. SE’s dispute with their upstream licensors is not something downstream licensors can resolve on their own without a lawyer, and I’m not one.

Comment: As such I’ve rolled back that edit. Those are not words you may put in my name. Mentioning the dispute might be worthwhile, but changing the link to point to a license that does not match the actual license statement from SE is not on.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My bad, I didn't mean it as legal advice; I wasn't aware SE still claimed they unilaterally retroactively changed the terms of the liscensing.  My impression from the meta Q&A I linked was that it is now more of 'all content going forward is liscensed this way, and we refuse to comment about the status of old content'.

Comment: @LiamMorris-ReinstateMonica There is a direct messaging system. Not sure how it works but I have been sent and replied to DMs before.

Comment: @jgn Aside from the possibility of making chat rooms, there is no "direct messaging" system built into the site except to the extent that diamond mods and SE staff can message individual users.

Comment: @jgn I too got private messages/comments from Mods, and it was with a less than pleasant context.  It's not a tool that is applicable in user to user situations.